# Different album art for songs in the same album

Tags: music, music-player, mp3, id3-tag, album-art

The MediaStore provider on Android is really screwed up.

On Android it isn't possible to define different cover art for songs in the same Album. Especially for compilations and "Various Artists" Albums. This is annoying!

PlayerPro was able to use ID3 Cover-Art instead of the MediaStore cover art, but this doesn't work since it has been updated.
Same goes for most music players for android, as they always use the MediaStore Class on Android to get the cover, and not their own implementation to get the ID3 embedded cover art.

To work around this issue, I can tag the Album-Artist tag on all files with the same Album tag:

```
Artist      Title       Album   AlbumArtist CoverTag    Displayed Cover
Daft Punk   Get lucky   Singles Daft Punk   get lucky   get lucky
Deftones    Bored       Singles Deftones    bored       get lucky
Avicii      Levels      Singles Avicii      levels      levels
Avicii      Wake me up  Singles Avicii      wake me up  wake me up
```

This work around will correctly display different covers for each of those songs, all in the "Singles" album, BUT not for the two different songs by Avicii. It's because the Mediastore Class will allow different covers for different "AlbumArtists" on a single Album. Since the AlbumArtist tag for both Avicii songs are the same, it will only use one of the covers for all Avicii songs in the same album "Singles".

Solutions not preferred:

- Weird tag changes
- separate folders on the phone

**Any solution for PlayerPro, on Android itself, or my system of tagging? Or is there a different player which can handle embedded cover art correctly?**

Comment: What is **Weird tag changes**?

Comment: Sounds like this was bound to happen if you use the same album name for them all, and rely on the artist name to be unique. Why not put the single name in your album field, after that's what would be there if you had bought each song as a single rather than buying a compilation?

Comment: There are albums that have the same name. I use "Singles" for all songs in my collection that are released as a single. Another example is "The very best of" by Prince and by 5 other artists in my collection. They all use Prince's cover now. Which isn't preferred.